# Previewing/Updating some Pages causes "The requested URL was rejected" Error

Tags: php, urls, security

The wordpress site is suddenly having a problem where on some (not all) of the pages, when you click preview page or update changes it gives an error message:

"The requested URL was rejected. If you think this is an error, please contact the webmaster.

Your support ID is: 9641638102880218190"

This can be circumvented by entering the preview url directly into the browser or clicking "open in new tab" when you click the preview button. However you cannot right click and do this on the "Update" button so it does not solve my problem.

One thing I noticed is that these pages all tend to have 1 or more categories assigned to the page. Other than that I can't think of similarities between the pages it's occuring on.

So far I think it's caused by the PHP code... but this is my first wordpress site and I'm lost. Lots of googling showed that this has happened to others but there isn't a clear solution.

I've disabled some but not all my plugins since I do not want to lose data.

**please teach me how to debug this problem**

Answer (score 0):

It turns our this error is caused by security software on the server. Meaning that a software that makes sure the hosting providers servers are safe is denying these requests.

You cannot fix this because it's on the hosting providers server, you have to call or email them and let them know this is happening.

I did they and they looked into it and told me there was a bug that was causing this error. They fixed it on their end and told me things should be fine now and they were.

So call them, you cannot fix it without your hosting provider's help.